# Sencha chart - special stacked columns

Tags: javascript, charts, sencha-charts

I'm trying to do a special stacked column chart with Sencha and I'm wondering if somebody already did it?

The example is explained in Sencha [support forum](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?188139-Are-scatted-charts-possible-with-ExtJS-4.x-charting-library&p=756848#post756848) (what helpful support ;-) )

Solutions with other charting libraries are welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FusionCharts XT](http://www.fusioncharts.com/products/suite/) provides the chart type you require out of the box.

The chart type you want is essentially a "Stacked Column Multi-series" chart.

Here is a direct link to what you want - http://www.fusioncharts.com/demos/gallery/stacked-charts/chart.asp?id=msstackedcolumn2d_1

You can find the entire gallery for stacked charts here - http://www.fusioncharts.com/demos/gallery/#stacked-charts

Plus, FusionCharts XT has all JavaScript charts.

Comment: It's a bit too expensive for us, but yes they implement this special stack version.